# Android URL wont connect after service is running for a longer period

Tags: android, android-service, android-networking

I'm not sure how to even put a good title to this question.

I have the following class in my Android app:

```
class Translator {
    public Translator() {
    }

    public String bingTranslate(String text) throws IOException {

        String response;
        String textEncoded= URLEncoder.encode(text, "utf-8");

        String url = "https://www.bing.com/tdetect";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "UTF-8");

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        outputStreamWriter.write("text="+textEncoded);
        outputStreamWriter.flush();


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        response=in.readLine();
        in.close();
        con.disconnect();

        return response;

    }
}
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
detected = new Translator().bingTranslate(text.substring(0, Math.min(text.length(), 100)));
```

This works absolutely fine, however after my service runs for a long time (like a day or so), the URL fails to connect throwing me errors failed to connect. Force-stopping the service and restarting it makes the whole think work again.

My service is extending NotificationListenerService so it's always running, and it tries to use Bing to detect the language of some notifications.

The `detect` string is a local variable and the `Translator` class is not referenced anywhere else. First I thought it might somehow remain referenced because I was using the Translator class as a field.  But even after moving the Translator to a local call the problem still resurface.

What I noticed when the connection fails, the URL throws and error that it failed to connect to: `https://www.bing.com/204.79.197.200:443` which isn't really the URL string I used to make the call.

Am I'm missing the obvious or is this potentially a bug in Android?

As a footnote question any suggestion for an alternative to make the http call? I looked at [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) but that works with callbacks and I'm not too keen to make changes to my whole app to accommodate that.

**UPDATE**

I have now changed the code and switched over to [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) which seems to work fine even after 3 days, so far so good, but the question remains why the simple Https connection fails after some time? I was just not able to figure it out...

Comment: Why don't you use Retrofit? It's a widely used REST-library. You can even replace a request only in one class, retaining them in others.

Comment: @CoolMind - I haven't heard of it till now any link please?

Comment: 204.79.197.200:443 is the IP address of bing.com. Thats one thing.

Comment: Here is retrofit: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: A cool library! you can use it with reactive java too.

Comment: @uneq95 Thanks, I will have a look at it. Yeah I know that 204.79.197.200:443 is bing's IP, what I find strange is the format it appears in the logs, mix of IP+URL which I think it's odd.

Comment: @EmilBorconi, Retrofit can use callbacks or synchronous calls with RxJava (or coroutines in Kotlin), or with any other thread calls (ExecutorService, for instance).

Comment: Also, you wont need to change your whole app to use callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, I assume that you want the service to run infinitely, but it is only running for a day and throwing the exception.
What I believe is the Android OS is restricting your service to run for longer time due to some restriction Android team have introduced. Your service can't run for longer period of time because this long running services will drain a lot of battery and Android CPU resources.
If you are using the background service than this is not a proper solution for implementing the long running services, what I suggest is you use the **Foreground service** and let the application show one **notification**, this will not let the Android OS destroy your service.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I know about background service restirction and I know about foreground service. This isn't the case here. The service runs just fine all other functions of the service are working correctly, it's just the URL connection call which isn't working as expected.